# Override configuration properties in micronaut

Tags: java, microservices, micronaut

I have a micronaut application in which I want to override the default configuration properties based on a profile I pass through an environment variable.
Tha application has a default application.yml
I am currently passing:

```
MICRONAUT_CONFIG_FILES=classpath:application.yml,/path/to/application-prod.yml 
MICRONAUT_ENVIRONMENTS=prod
```

However just application-prod.yml is taken into account (unlike for Spring Boot where it updates the defaults).

What is the best way to achieve the update? The only solution so far is to replicate all the settings in application-prod.yml but it seems pretty anti-DRY.

Comment: Is `application.yml` on your CLASSPATH?

Comment: Yes, it is. It's in the root of the shaded jar file.